# CoTURN and PostgreSQL Setup

Tags: postgresql, coturn

I'm setting up CoTURN server for my WebRTC application. I want to use PostgreSQL as the user's database.

I'm started up turnserver with the option `--psql-userdb`. I'm getting an error below.

```
turnserver: unrecognized option `--psql-userdb=...`
```

When I'd tried to start the server without any options, I got these logs below.

```
RFC 3489/5389/5766/5780/6062/6156 STUN/TURN Server
Version Coturn-4.5.0.6 'dan Eider'
0: 
Max number of open files/sockets allowed for this process: 8191
0: 
Due to the open files/sockets limitation,
max supported number of TURN Sessions possible is: 4000 (approximately)
0: 
==== Show him the instruments, Practical Frost: ====
0: TLS supported
0: DTLS supported
0: DTLS 1.2 supported
0: TURN/STUN ALPN supported
0: Third-party authorization (oAuth) supported
0: GCM (AEAD) supported
0: OpenSSL compile-time version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017 (0x1010006f)
0: 
0: SQLite supported, default database location is /usr/local/var/db/turndb
0: Redis is not supported
0: PostgreSQL is not supported
0: MySQL supported
0: MongoDB is not supported
0: 
0: Default Net Engine version: 1 (UDP listening socket per session)
```

It says that PostgreSQL is not supported, although I have installed PostgreSQL 9.3.

Is there any missing on my setting or is there a way to tell turnserver to enable support to a selected database?

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe need to recompile with postgresql enabled?  the debian package for co-turn,  how ae you installing.  may need to install libpq-devel before compiling?

Comment: I'm using macOS. Is there a way to tell which path is my postgresql during the ./configure?